# Selecting more than one country to be highlighted

Tags: qgis, query

I can get a one country within a world shapefile to highlight, but when it comes to adding additional countries this just turns all countries back on

[image]

I am using query builder to achieve highlighting Mali, but really want to highlight Burkina Faso and Niger

If I do `"admin" = 'Mali'` this works but if I do `"admin" = 'mali' AND 'burkina faso'` this doesn't work

I have also tried doing

```
"admin" = 'mali'

"admin" = 'burkina faso'
```

This doesn't work either

Comment: Thank you for your post, it was very helful, I managed to "highlight" two country Argentina and Bolivia using the script as you discribed. Awesome! Thanks[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5VA1.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5VA1.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to combine the different countries with an OR operator, because one feature does not contain all names at once.

This should work:

```
"admin" = 'mali' OR "admin" = 'burkina faso' OR "admin" = 'niger'
```

Comment: Yes, that worked - Thanks

Comment: You can get the same results with `IN` instead of equals, like this: `"admin" IN ('mali', 'burkina faso', 'niger')`. This method is good when you have a long list.